# Crosscorrelation in a c shell using While loop

Tags: shell-script

I am new in C shell, and I am trying to do cross-correlation in the script. I have 151 seismic traces. My job is to choose the first trace (as a master trace) and cross-correlate it all other traces. After, this time master trace is gonna be 2nd trace, and this time it is gonna be cross-correlated with 1st trace and all other traces. It goes like this until the master trace is gonna be the 151st trace.

I am using this on seismic Unix. After running, it gives an error this; "illegal variable name".

My script like this:

```
#!/bin/csh
segyread tape=normalized_20_From_Deep_to_Surface_B1.segy > vsp1.su
set data = vsp1.su
set a = 1
while ( $a <= 151 )
   suwind key=tracl min=$a max=$a < $data > master_trace$a.su
   fconv verbose=1 file_in1=$data file_in2=master_trace$.su mode=cor1 shift=0 > 
   xcor_20_sources_B1_output.su
   suxwigb < xcor_20_sources_B1_output.su 
end
```

Thanx

Comment: Your script is pretty much unreadable, please use the formatting notation SE offers. In addition, you might want to remove the `loop-device` tag, it doesn't mean what you think it means :-) Third, to find out what's wrong with your script, run it with the `-x` option so you see what commands are executed. It's very likely that you can find a coding error that way.

Comment: also use the `shellcheck` tool.

Comment: Does the error message say anything else?

Comment: Ask this in the Seismic Unix forum list.